# CopyFromRecordset only copying over 65535 rows?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, recordset

I am writing some code in MS Access VBA.

I have an MS Access query with 110,000 rows and I am trying to copy them over to an Excel spreadsheet, but when I call

xlWorksheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

It's only porting over 65535 rows. Is there a way to make it port over the entire set?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @teylyn Access and Excel are both 2010 version

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3e602bd1-4db2-45bd-85ed-c925894e7048/exporting-large-recordsets-to-excel-stops-at-65536-records-after-upgrade-to-office-2010?forum=accessdev

Comment: Another one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/25e413a1-57c3-407a-9e26-3bb124610e3d/output-limit-for-the-copyfromrecordset-method?forum=accessdev

Comment: I am pretty sure this Excel file is not being opened in compatibility mode

Comment: @user525966 my link suggests that it is a limit to the clipboard and as such one would need to use a different method to avoid the clipboard.

Comment: I got it working by closing the workbook opening and re-opening it, for some reason now it has the full rows and not just 65536 -- wish I didn't have to do that though

Answer (score 0):

The excel file you are using is having .xls format most probably or any other incompatible one. from the next time change your excel file format and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2003 or older, 65,535 is a hard limit.  If you have Excel 2007 or newer, there are so, so, so many ways to do this.  Here is one version of countless ways to do this.

```
Sub ExportDataToExcel()
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim myRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strConn As String

   strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & "C:\your_path_here\Northwind.mdb"

   Set myRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

   FocusRow = ActiveCell.Row
   With myRecordset
       .Open "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value, _
         strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

      .Fields("ID").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("FName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("LName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("Address").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & FocusRow).Value
      .Fields("Age").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & FocusRow).Value
      .Update
      .Close
   End With
   Set myRecordset = Nothing
   Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```